# Pandas: Adding 0 to a long integer representing a date

Tags: python, pandas, date, date-conversion

I am trying to import a csv into panda. This csv contains a data column as follow (for instance):

20170607155749330: (Year/Month/Day/Hour/Minute/Second/decisecond/centisecond/millisecond). So there are 17 numbers representing the date.

Issue I have is that for this particular dataset is that some row have dates at a different precision, for instance:
2017060715581995 : here there are only 16 numbers since the millisecond is missing.

What I want to do is simple: converting every date for every row in a way that I would end up with 17 digit, by adding a 0 when one of them is missing.

Here is the function I wrote for this:

```
def convert_value(val):
   return ('{:0<17}'.format(val))
```

So I try to apply it to every row by just creating a new column such as:

```
file_temp['Time_Transformed'] = file_temp.apply( lambda x: convert_value(x["TIME"]) , axis =1)
```

And I am facing two issues:

1. Firstly, the newly created column is not of integer but of object type;
2. Secondly, it just does not work, 0 is not added to shorter date.

I tried various other approaches by converting the original data to string but they are not working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) with [`str.ljust`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.ljust.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[20170607155749330,20170607155749]})

df['new'] = df['A'].astype(str).str.ljust(17, '0').astype('int64')
print (df)
                   A                new
0  20170607155749330  20170607155749330
1     20170607155749  20170607155749000
```

And for datetime:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'].astype(str).str.ljust(17, '0'), format='%Y%m%d%M%S%f')
print (df)
                   A                       date
0  20170607155749330 2017-06-07 00:15:57.493300
1     20170607155749 2017-06-07 00:15:57.490000
```

is same as:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'], format='%Y%m%d%M%S%f')
print (df)
                   A                       date
0  20170607155749330 2017-06-07 00:15:57.493300
1     20170607155749 2017-06-07 00:15:57.490000
```

Comment: Fine it is working! Now I have a question when I try to use pd.to_datetime I get the error 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'. I tried to google it but I do not see any solution.

Comment: You need select column of DataFrame, so check `print (df.columns)` and then use `pd.to_datetime(df[colname], format='%Y%m%d%M%S%f')`. So if column is `0` need `pd.to_datetime(df['0'], format='%Y%m%d%M%S%f')` or `pd.to_datetime(df[0], format='%Y%m%d%M%S%f')`

Comment: Thank you for your help but I still have the same issue apparently my data frame for a particular reason do not have the 'to_datetime' module? I checked my version of pandas it is 0.20.1

Comment: Maybe typo, not `df.to_datetime` byt `pd.to_datetime`

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `ljust` string method and convert to integer. Starting from a simple dataframe:

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame([20170607155749330,20170607155749])

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
                   0
0  20170607155749330
1     20170607155749
```

we can add a column with:

```
In [11]: df['T'] = df[0].apply(lambda x: int(str(x).ljust(17,'0')))

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
                   0                  T
0  20170607155749330  20170607155749330
1     20170607155749  20170607155749000
```

basically we use the `ljust(17,'0')` which adds `0` to a fixed length of 17 at the end of your integer now as string, and convert back everything to integer.

Answer (score 0):

The following plain vanilla (string manipulation) Python will do the trick:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def conv_date(date__):
    date_ = str(date__)
    len_ = len(date_)

    if len_ == max_:
        return date__
    else:
        return int(date_ + '0' * (max_ - len_))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    max_ = 17
    dates = [20170607155749330, 2017060715581995]
    for date_ in dates:
        print(date_, "\t", conv_date(date_))
```

Namely, the output is:

```
20170607155749330        20170607155749330
2017060715581995         20170607155819950
```